# Ok, EAGLE eyes... what am I missing here?

Tags: power, eaglecad

Ok, so most of my schematic is completed, and I've cleared all the ERC checks but this one. I don't seem to see what the problem is.

all the positive powers are connected using the same (copy paste) v+ symbol, but the ones attached to the IC seem to be warning me. something to worry about, or just ignore?

[image: error]

Comment: It doesnt mean anything is wrong with you connections, it's just a sort of a reminder to tell you your power connections.

Comment: I'm not an Eagle user, but it appears to be pointing out a discrepancy between the definition in the schematic symbol and the net you've connected it to. I guess that leaves you with three options- change the net name, change the symbol definition, or ignore. I don't like to see any DRC errors or warnings so the last one would irritate me. If you had 25 or 30 chips the cascade of warnings might obscure something of importance.

Comment: @kelvinmead - I do use Eagle. I believe Spehro Pefhany has diagnosed it correctly. As long as the pin is actually connected to the correct net, then you are fine. Spehro Pefhany has also described the solution. I would be tempted to rename one or the other (depending on ease) to match. Of course, you can simply 'Approve' the errors. They don't go away, but are retained in a list of 'Approved warnings', so Eagle won't lose the information.

Comment: I second what @SpehroPefhany and gbulmer said. One of you should combine that into an answer.

Comment: I guess I should have realised that humans are trained to collate data, but computers see them as different entities. I see V+ and Vdd to be the same thing, but Eagle sees them differently! Simple, but stupid! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all the circuit diagram editors I've used will point out discrepancies on pins designated as power pins on an IC. Usually (I can't say this is absolutely correct for Eagle) when a pin is designated as a power pin, the pin name expects to be connected to a net with the same label. You've wired a power pin called Vdd to a net called V+ and there's nothing wrong at all with this but you could: -

1. Rename the net
2. Rename the pin
3. Don't connect it but connect a power symbol (named Vdd) to V+ and you should find that all power pins called Vdd get connected to V+ (This works with OrCAD btw)

It's only a warning so nothing to get worried about but, like Spehro, I hate warnings and do everything to get rid of them because, like he says, it's easy to miss a "real" warning amongst the advisory ones.

If you do go for #3 make sure the power pins do net up when converting to a layout file.

Comment: Yes, "power"-type pins in EAGLE are really lame. They don't give you the option of connecting them to any signal other than the one *defined in the part library* without a warning (or worse). It's just too restrictive for general use. I always define the power pins to be "passive".

Comment: I've had this happen with op amps in Eagle.  I had to do some voodoo command to make the power pins "appear" on the component, then I was able to connect them to whatever I needed to connect them to.  Does anybody know why Eagle does this?  Why not just show me all the damned pins?

Comment: @JoeRounceville If it's like OrCAD you can hide pins named Vcc and GND and they automatically pick up a connection to a net that has the same name - saves your schematic getting cluttered - I can only trust that the same is true of Eagle.

Comment: That's probably what it's doing. I think the problem is that I don't always name a net "Vcc" or "GND".  It might be "V+5" or "AGND" and "DGND"... I'd prefer that it popped up and said something like "I don't see a net called Vcc or GND, what net would you like to connect this op amp to?"  Either that, or just show the pins, and give me an option to hide nets easily if I want.  I think it's confusing having warnings pop up that you have to do secret stuff to deal with.  Oh well.